# Is it possible to schedule intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

I studied about Job Scheduler API for scheduling background tasks and also that one intent can be fired multiple times at regular intervals.But could not understand how to apply them to my problem.

My problem is that I am making an emergency app and for that purpose i need that when i press the alert button, tasks like sending message ,phone call be done  immediately  with small time interval between 2 tasks.

So ,Is it possible to schedule the intents for text message and phone call such that there is some  seconds between firing of two intents on button click?

Is it possible to use Timer or Job Scheduler for this purpose?

Please can anybody guide?

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) can help you.

Take a look at [set](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and [setRepeating](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) methods

Hope it helps,